# Android NavigationDrawerFragment: Control whether the child fragment or parent activity's onCreateOptionsMenu gets called, but not both

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

So like I mentioned in the title, I have a setup with a NavigationDrawerFragment and another fragment in a containing activity.

Ideally I'd like my behavior to be something as follow.

1. When the drawer is opened, call the containing activities onCreateOptionsMenu but do not call the other fragment's (the current visible fragment's) onCreateOptionsMenu.
2. When the drawer is closed, calling the visible fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu method but do not call the containing fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu method.

Is there anyway to achieve this using lifecycle callbacks? Or should I look into using an event bus instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity let have this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuInflater inflater, Menu menu){
  boolean onlyFragments = !mDrawerLayout.isOpened(GravityCompat.START);
  Fragment visibleFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_layout);
  visibleFragment.setHasOptionsMenu(onlyFragments);
  if(onlyFragments){
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(inflater,menu);
  }else{
     //here only activity inflates menu
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
     return true;
  }
}
```

and in `onDrawerClosed(View v)` and `onDrawerOpened(View v)` call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` or it's respective support method.

Comment: I guess this works, I wish I didn't have to dynamically on the fly change life cycle looks, any other ideas would be great but works for now